# How do I get a list of all available entities in a Source engine game?

Tags: modding, source-engine

How do I get a list of all available entities in a Source engine game?

There is only one exported function in the server DLL - `CreateInterface` - so it's not an option. In GoldSrc games, the server DLL features all entities as exported functions.

Comment: Do you mean all available entity classes, or all available entity instances in a level?

Comment: Entity classes.

Comment: 7 years late, but you can use the console command `dumpentityfactories` in-game.